# Rails 4 - random error with turbolinks, sprockets, stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, sprockets, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4 with Bootstrap 2.3.2 and have been noticing a seemingly random error that I can't figure out.  I suspect it might have something to do with incompatibility between turbolinks and Twitter Bootstrap.

Can somebody help me identify the problem?  Apologies for the lengthy post below but I wanted to provide as much info as possible.  Thanks!

Here's the error:

```
Errno::EINVAL in StaticPages#home

Showing /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
Invalid argument - /tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/13fe41fee1fe35b49d145bcc06610705
```

Here's the extracted code from /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Name</title>
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
       <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
       <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
       <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
```

The problem is in the 4th line in the code above:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Here's the framework trace:

```
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:27:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:27:in `open'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:27:in `open'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:27:in `[]='
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:34:in `cache_set'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:92:in `cache_set_hash'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:68:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:144:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:113:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:112:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:112:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__203810741__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__76538721__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: I'm no expert in looking at traces, but it seems that one of your asset dependencies is missing? That's about the best help I can give sorry :(

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I'll look into asset dependencies with the relevant gems.  But, if an asset dependency is missing, why does that application work correctly 99% of the time?

Comment: I'm not super sure to be honest - there are a lot of things which could go wrong. Is there any way you could define the specific events which will trigger the error?